# wien bridge oscillator distortion

Tags: oscillator, distortion

I built simple wien oscillator.  How to reduce distortion of the sine wave?

Leads was as short as can be, soldered "Manhattan style".

Tried 2x KD305D power supplies as well as split battery source. This didnt helped.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too much gain ,you are clipping .Reduce the 220K resister.

Comment: The [LM358](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/LM358.pdf) is also not a rail-to-rail output op-amp... try powering from +/-5v and see if that clears things up.

Comment: The 220k resistor value is so higth that the dsiodes are not limiting the output lef\vel

Comment: For those interested by the subject, the [HP-200C](https://people.ohio.edu/postr/bapix/HP200C.htm) audio oscillator was a Wien-bridge-based oscillator whose internal gain amplitude was stabilized by a light bulb, object of patent [2,268,272](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ef/51/de/90447294860fc6/US2268872.pdf) from Bill Hewlett in 1939.

Comment: There are other oscillator alternatives with better distortion properties - for example: Integrator-based topolgies (2 or 3 opamps) or bandpass-based oscillators (1 opamp) having a better selectivity as the WIEN-network (Q=1/3 only).

Answer (score 1):

The LM358 output will swing almost to the negative power rail but will only get within about 2V of the positive power rail. So I think you are seeing clipping on the positive swing but distortion on the negative going output swing. I have tried to use that diode amplitude controlling technique before which resulted in a distorted output. I Got much better results with this J-FET based design.

[image: Wien Oscillator]

Comment: Thank You for answers ! I will try another rail to raill, with higher bandwith op amp. And will try J FET to control gain.

Answer (score 1):

So many problems.

1: clipping.

the signal amplitude is too high, increase "10k"
until the flat tops disappear.
clipping also provokes saturation, this may be responsble for the step that appears after the crests.

2: power supply.

LM358 really wants 6 times more voltage from the supply,  it's work on 5V but badly.

3: cross-over distortion.

LM358 is infamous for cross-over distortion,
this can cause flat spots in the middle of slopes.

4: diodes.

Wein bridge works better with a slower part setting the gain, this is why precision Wein bridges use thermistors to set the gain, LM358 is not strong enough to keep a thermistor warm so this may not be an easy option.
this is certainly the least of the problems.

Comment: Another cause of the "step" is an op-amp emerging from saturation...a process that can take time.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot that, once the clipping is fixed the saturatuion will not happen.  edited answer.

Comment: Will follow Your advice ! Thanks !